# Zabbix Configuration for Monitoring Multiple Tomcat JVM on Single Host via JMX

Tags: tomcat, jmx, zabbix

I have  multiple instance of Tomcat on a single host running on different port. I have enabled JMX  on each  tomcat instance with 2 different port (9999 & 9998).

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.1.2.3
```

and

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9998
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9998
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.1.2.3
```

I would like to monitor both jvm  via zabbix. I'm using a Generic JVM template.I'm able to add a  single  JMX Interface via Configuration>Host>Create New Host >JMX Interface : 10.1.2.3:9999. I can view the Metrics/Graphs on zabbix.

Is it possible to another JMX entry (10.1.2.3:9998) under the same host ? Or do i need to create another host entry for port 9998 ? What is the best way to do it ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot have more than one JMX on the same host. Unfortunatelly you have to create a new host per each JMX that you want to monitor.
I have the same issue right now, I have 2 JVM instances running on the same machine and I was trying to monitor both on the same host but is not possible. I'm not quite sure why you can add multiples JMX interfaces if you cannot monitor multiples JXM (at least using Templates)

Comment: Thank you for answering.